# SelectedItem in combobox and observablecollection

Tags: c#, combobox, observablecollection, selecteditem

i was create this class

```
class update
{
    //public static List<user_struct> list_lot = new List<user_struct> { };
    public static ObservableCollection<update> list_update = new ObservableCollection<update>();
    public update(String urle)
    {
        Urle = urle;
    }

    public string Urle { get; set; }
}
```

and this combobox

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,108,0,0" x:Name="update_website" SelectionChanged="update_website_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340"  DisplayMemberPath="Urle"  IsEditable="False" />
```

and when i want to use SelectItem.ToString() it's giving me the name of my project and class like this passbase.update

Thank you.

Comment: So..., what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the ToString method will just return the class's full name. If you want your ToString method to return something else, such as the value of the Urle property, then you can override the ToString method in your 'update' class.

```
class update
{
    public static ObservableCollection<update> list_update = 
        new ObservableCollection<update>();

    public update(String urle)
    {
        Urle = urle;
    }

    public string Urle { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Urle;
    }
}
```